# What is the difference between iText, JasperReports and Adobe LC?

Tags: jasper-reports, adobe, itext

Actually I want to know the difference or comparison between different PDF Creation/generation techniques For Eg. IText,Adobe LC,Jasper Reports etc.

I would like to know the exact advantage/disadvantage of using each of them.

Currently I am using Adobe LC ES2 and would like to also know the advantage of using adobe over other techniques.

Thanks,
AS

Answer (score 6):

That's a very broad question and I see that it already has a vote to close the question for this reason.

Let me give the nutshell version of the answer (I could easily write a book about it).

iText is a library that can be used by developers to enhance their web and other applications with PDF functionality: create PDF, fill out PDF forms, examine and manipulate existing PDFs.

JasperReports is a Business Intelligence tool that uses iText to create reports by JasperSoft / TIBCO. JasperReports only uses a limited part of the complete iText functionality. Creating PDF is just a feature of JasperReports, and JasperSoft is using iText to implement that feature.

Adobe LC is a suite of modules, some of which can only be provided by Adobe. For instance: no third party can "Reader enable" PDF documents because Reader enabling requires a private key that is proprietary to Adobe. However: iText competes with Adobe LC in some areas, for instance digital signing (read [the white paper from the Office of Legislative Counsel on digital signatures](http://www.mnhs.org/preserve/records/legislativerecords/docs_pdfs/CA_Authentication_WhitePaper_Dec2011.pdf)) or form filling (iText has an add-on called [XFA Worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xfa_worker) that can convert your dynamic XFA forms into static PDF, e.g. PDF/A).

DISCLAIMER: I'm the CEO of iText Software. Please contact Adobe and JasperSoft to hear their point of view.